# How to setup Whenever gem in production (RVM)

Tags: ruby, cron, rvm, whenever

I've one rake task which i want to execute once every day:
in production installed rvm

in **schedule.rb** i have

```
set :output, "/home/username/data/public_html/log/cron_log.log"
every 24.hours do
  rake "fetch:smth"
end
```

crontab -l shows me:

```
MAILTO="my.mail@gmail.com"
PATH="/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby "
@daily cd /home/username/data/www/nameofsite.com && RAILS_ENV=production bundle   exec rake fetch:smth
```

truly, i'm a little bit confused, coz previously i didn't have experience with cron, so plz help.

**EDIT #1**

i've run **rvm env -- path 1.9.3@global**
and it gave me:

```
PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH"
```

and then i've

```
MAILTO="said.kaldybaev@gmail.com"
PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH"
@daily  RAILS_ENV=production rake rate:fetch
```

and when i run execute, from ISPmanager, it gave me: *Exited with return code = 1*
the [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/mcron/manual/html_node/Exit-codes.html) below says that if the exit error is 1, then there is already a /var/run/cron.pid file. and it's true, but i don't have root privileges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `schedule.rb` if you're calling the task from cron.  That's handled by the `@daily` entry in crontab.  Just set the logfile name as an environment variable and have the rake task refer to that.  You'll probably also need more in your `$PATH` than just the path to the ruby binary, otherwise `bundle` isn't going to be found.  While you're giving the path to a ruby, you're not actually selecting it for RVM to know what you mean, so it's not going to be able to find the right gemset.  RVM provides wrappers which Do The Right Thing for this sort of task - replace `bundle exec` with `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p125 -S bundle exec` and it should work.

Hope that gives you some ideas.  There's more [here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/cron/).

*UPDATE #1*

With Edit #1, you've fixed one problem and created another.  You still need to `cd` to the app directory, otherwise rake won't find the Rakefile.

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev that's misleading! Othe people (such a smyself) might find the same issue and think this answer solved your problem!